# is there a way to represent a str with an int in pandas dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

was wondering if there's a way to represent a string with an int without converting it?
for instance be able to represent January with 01 etc. any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi Mitchell, welcome to Stackoverflow. It's important when you ask something, you provide a reproducible example with the outputs expect, that's aspects help we can resolve your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by representing a string with an int without converting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if/elif` in a `function`.

For example :

```
def represent(in):
    if(in == 01):
        return "January"
    .
    .
    .
```

Or you can use `try/except` Like below :

```
def RepresentsInt(s):
    try: 
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

>>> print RepresentsInt("+123")
True
>>> print RepresentsInt("10.0")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary with all months of year, in this example I create a dictionary with the first six months:

```
months = {
    'January': '01',
    'February': '02',
    'March': '03',
    'April': '04',
    'May': '05',
    'June': '06'
}
```

Then, suppose you have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'months': ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June']})
```

Output:

```
    months
0   January
1   February
2   March
3   April
4   May
5   June
```

You can do something like this in order to create a column with another representation for your months:

```
df['months_another_representation'] = df['months'].map(months)
```

Output:

```
    months  months_another_representation
0   January     01
1   February    02
2   March       03
3   April       04
4   May         05
5   June        06
```

If you want to read more about `map()` function, click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html). All Values of the month column must match with the dictionary's keys. I hope this example can help you.